# Achieving property value assignment control using a generic approach for POCO or plain C# entity classes

Tags: c#, authorization

I am working on a .NET application & trying to achieve following in C#.

Let's assume we have an entity as ***Employee*** class below with few public auto implemented properties.
Assume we have created an attribute say - BeforePropertySet & we have annotated some of the entity properties with it - as in the class below.

```
class Employee
{
    [BeforePropertySet("Some Delegate", "some other Prop value")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int age { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to do can be explained with help of code snippet -

```
var e = new Employee();
e.Address = "confidential data";  
//this assignment is restricted for user X
//whereas allowed for user Y
e.Name = "general data";
```

Whenever I **assign** value to a property, if that property is annotated with this special attribute *BeforePropertySet* then it will callback a common function which will do some standard thing across application. For example, if currentUser is not expected to view the Value being assigned then the new value assignment can be cancelled.

This approach enables me to remove attribute or add to new entities easily.

I found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/141732/Automatic-Implementation-of-INotifyPropertyChanged) approach which can allow me to invoke another function with few changes of invocation in inherited class, but it is an auto-generated inherited class & instance needs to be explicitly created for this approach.

Have anyone already tried this? Please let me know know how can I achieve this or please point to any other resources that you may know. Appreciate help. Many thanks.

Comment: You should look at Aspect Orientated Programming

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to who gave probable answers. Posting it here for sake of completeness. Here is why & how I changed path & still achieved the business goal in my application.

After discussion with my team the attribute based approach was cancelled. 
The main reason was to have ability to change data protection policy dynamically without revisiting the code.
With this in mind, I ended up doing following.

1) Defined the metadata inside an xml & cached it.
2) All model conversion/creation - assignments happen in one single class per model.
3) Added one helper method which checks in xml if current user has access to protected data based on xml config & assigns appropriate value.

XML Looks something like -

```
 <ModelTag Name="SomeModelName">
    <Property defaultReturnValue="0" roles="userrole1, userrole2">PropertyName1</Property>
  </ModelTag>
```

And new C# code looks like -

```
Employee e  = new Employee();
e.PropertyName1 = (CheckAccess(e,"PropertyName1") ? "new value2" : null);
e.PropertyName2 = (CheckAccess(e,"PropertyName1") ? "new value2" : null);


bool CheckAccess(model m, string propName)
{
    var currentRole = GetCurrentRole();  //some method to retrive Role of current user
    //Retrieve xml for model m from cache
    //Check if XML configuration provides access to values of propName to currentRole
    //Return true or false accordingly
}
```

I hope this will help someone.